# C/ASM. Неблокирующий ввод в консоли

Tags: c, ассемблер, консоль, вывод, ввод

Нужно написать чат на ассемблере(пока что прототипирую на С), проблема в том, что нужно одновременно обновлять приходящие сообщения и иметь возможность писать новое сообщение, не знаю, как можно это реализовать.
Сейчас имеется следующий код:

```
while(1)
{
    printf("Please enter the message: ");
        bzero(buff,256);
        fgets(buff,255,stdin);

        printf("\nSending to SERVER: %s ",buff);

    /* Send message to the server */
        in = send(fd,buff,strlen(buff),0);
        if (in < 0) 
        {
         perror("\nClient Error: Writing to Server");
            return 0;
        }

    /* Now read server response */
        bzero(buff,256);
        in = recv(fd,buff,255,0);
        if (in < 0) 
        {
         perror("\nClient Error: Reading from Server");
        return 0;
        }
        printf("\nReceived FROM SERVER: %s ",buff);
}
```

Проблема в том, что здесь приём ведётся последовательно с передачей, функция fgets блокирует дальнейшее движение по циклу.
Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: это решают отдельным потоком

Comment: Или неблокирующим `read`.

Comment: Вместо fgets читайте по  одному символу, например, с помощью cin.get() или иным методом, возвращающим без ожидания один символ, если он есть, и пустую строку либо EOF, если символа нет, и складывайте полученное в буфер. А если получите в качестве очередного символа Enter - отправляйте получившееся сообщение и зачищайте буфер. И не забудьте соотв. образом обрабатывать Backspace и прочие не очень символьные комбинации... Когда перейдёте на АСМ, будете читать с помощью Int 16h.

Comment: @Akina, а int 16h -- это прерывание DOS? Просто я пишу на Linux.

Comment: Ну тады по INT 9h отслеживайте нажатие, и там хоть самостоятельно обрабатывайте, хоть из буфера черпайте - дело Ваше.

Comment: @PaulShishmarev ещё можно через `poll/select`, и через обработку сигнала `SIGIO`.